# Android shortcuts (Pin Shortcuts) : how to remove the '1x1' label?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-shortcutmanager

I create a pinned shortcut for my app using:

```
mShortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(mShortcutInfo, null);
```

as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts).

My problem is that I have a '1x1' label in the system dialog box displayed by Android as shown below:

[image]

My question is : how to remove this '1x1' label ? (I have also no idea what it means...)

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you can remove it. I believe 1 x 1 is simply the space it will take. Like your home screen is a grid, for example 4 x 6. Icons take up 1 x 1 but some widgets take a larger space.

Comment: To be clear, this label is *not* part of the shortcut that will show up in the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is that "1 X 1"

---

"1 x 1" is just like the ratio of space it will take. All the app icons take up a space of 1x1. It can also be taken as the ratio or height and width. 1x1 = 1:1(here). This will mean that height is equal to width and thus, the space taken will be in the shape of a square.

#### How can we remove it?

---

This label can NOT be removed as it is a part of the OS which helps the user know how much space it will take. There is NO way it can be removed.

Hope you were answered